# Finding a message across multiple folder trees with one call with microsoft-graph java sdk

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In converting from an older bit of code that uses the EWS (`ews-java-api v 2.0`) SDK/API/Scope to Graph (`microsoft-graph v5.4.0`), I found that I could search (say by InternetMessageId) across multiple folder hierarchies at once in EWS with (simplifying how to get FolderId values a bit):

```
SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection filter =
            new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And);
filter.add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.InternetMessageId, msgId));
List<FolderId> folders = Arrays.asList(new FolderId("AllItems"), new FolderId("Deletions"));
ItemView view = new ItemView(10);
ServiceResponseCollection<FindItemResponse<Item>> findResultsCollection =
            service.findItems(searchFolders, filter, null, view, null, ReturnErrors);
```

With that EWS search whether my message of interest is in the Inbox, some user-created sub-folder, JunkEmail, DeletedItems, RecoverableItemsDeletions I find it by InternetMessageId in one go.

With Graph I issue two calls to be able to ensure the message does not exist

```
UserRequestBuilder u = GraphServiceClient
      .builder()
      .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
      .buildClient()
      .users(user);

for (String folderTree : Arrays.asList("AllItems", "RecoverableItemsDeletions")) {
    MessageCollectionPage mcp = u.mailFolders(folderTree)
      .messages()
      .buildRequest()
      .filter("internetMessageId eq '" + msgId + "'")
      .get();
```

Is there a way to search multiple trees in one go with Graph to be more like the EWS path that took a List?

Answer (score 0):

**Use List Messages endpoint to get the messages in the signed-in user's mailbox** (including the Deleted Items and Clutter folders).

Depending on the page size and mailbox data, getting messages from a mailbox can incur multiple requests. The default page size is 10 messages. Use $top to customize the page size, within the range of 1 and 1000.

To improve the operation response time, use $select to specify the exact properties you need. Refer documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java).

Java Code Snippet -

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

MessageCollectionPage messages = graphClient.me().messages()
    .buildRequest()
    .select("sender,subject")
    .get();
```

Comment: This sample code gets messages from the AllItems tree. RecoverableItemsDeletions is not part of that tree, so this doesn't help.